# Why is "he seems doesn't need the money" wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

Instead of

> he seems [to] **doesn't need** the money

(I'm not sure about `to`)

The grammar editor suggests:

> he seems **not to need** the money

Doesn't `need` get negative with `doesn't`?

Comment: The non-negative version of the sentence is - **He seems *to need the money*.** Now you want to turn *to need the money* into a negative construction. To make a *to-infinitive* clause into negative all we need to do is add **"not"** either before or after **"to"**. So the whole sentence becomes - **He seems *not to need the money*.** or **He seems *to not need the money*.** When **need** is the main verb (*not* model verb) of the sentence/clause, the negative is **doesn't/don't need**.

Comment: Thanks  @Man_From_India . Very clear comment. I wonder why didn't you just make it an answer. And I don't have the privilege of upvoting comments yet.

Comment: @Man_From_India This would make a good answer.  I would also include a suggestion of "He *doesn't seem* to need the money."

Comment: @flower Welcome to the site.  It's good practice to wait before accepting an answer to a question.  I'm not suggesting that oerkelens's answer is incorrect, just that a superior answer might be forthcoming.  :-)

Comment: Thanks @JasonPatterson . The accepted answer seemed convincing enough to me. About superior you might be right. But what can do now; It's a moral dilemma :D

Comment: It's not a major issue, just a good habit.  Again, I'm not saying that it was a bad answer at all.  *He doesn't seem to need the money.* sounds most natural to my ear.  *He seems not to need the money.* and *It seems he doesn't need the money.* are perfectly grammatical and idiomatically correct though.  There are a number of ways to say this particular sentence.

Comment: @JasonPatterson Thanks for mentioning the alternate. It sounds a good choice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, every verb needs a *subject*.

In your sentence, the only subject is *he*, and that subject already has a verb: *seems*. You can not just add extra verbs to the sentence without extra subjects.

*Doesn't* does not have a subject in your sentence. *He* could be the subject, but it already is the subject of *seems*! If _doesn't also has *he* as a subject, we have two verbs, and only one subject.

The correct construction to use is *verb+to+infinitive*, where *seems* is the verb and *need* is an infinitive. And to make it negative, you just add *not*: *verb+not+to+infinitive*.

I just realized, you may have been thinking of this sentence:

> It seems he doesn't need the money.

In that case, *it* is the subject of *seems* and *he* is the subject of *doesn't*. This is an very different kind of sentence, thanks to that one little extra word!

Comment: Using `don't` in place of `doesn't` was my unintended mistake. I'll edit the question to avoid more complexion. Thanks

Comment: But also be aware that, particularly in informal speech, the subject or object of a verb can be implied, that is, not stated explicitly. So be a bit careful in applying "every verb needs a subject". To be fair, the statement was prefaced by "In general" - this is one of the exceptions.